# Handbrake-cli updated and now does not work

Tags: video-conversion, handbrake

I updated handbrake-cli using aptitude upgrade, as well as the codecs and now when I try to convert a file it keeps giving me an error "MP4 muxer disabled". Does any one know what the problem is?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The repo version is broken. I found a comment from the author, I really can't remember where but he acknowledges the official version is no good.

Good news is that he's got a PPA that works well and works flawlessly on my system.

Here's the terminal stuff -

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

He said he'll get it fixed in due course, once he's figured out what went wrong.

Comment: Confirming this answer, the link for Ubuntu from the HandBrake website points to https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases

Comment: Go careful here, there are two repos from Stebbins. *-releases are the stable Ubuntu versions which have not worked in the past, and seem to be the same as the one in the Ubuntu offical repos. The *-snapshots PPA I mentioned above is known to work and is the one I use consistently.

Comment: I'm going to add an amendment here. The Stebbins PPA/handbrake-releases are now working fine and I have changed from the nightly *snapshots as they can be unstable from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

Just `sudo apt-get upgrade` didnt do it for me. Needed to run `sudo apt-get upgrade handbrake-cli` to get it actually upgraded (or downgraded?).

Comment: Thank you! The same applied to me in Ubuntu Server 14.04