# Errors while installing handbrake and handbrake-cli

Tags: handbrake

I need the handbrake-cli tool, and I believe it does not come with the standard Ubuntu repository, so I followed this [guide](http://stormsail.com/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_HandBrakeCLI_on_ubuntu_12.04).

### Adding the repository

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots
sudo apt-get update
```

No errrors, everything seems fine.

### Everything seems fine through the installation:

```
jdoe@jdoe:~$ sudo apt-get install -y handbrake-cli handbrake-gtk 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libjansson4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  handbrake-cli handbrake-gtk libjansson4
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 16.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 36.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libjansson4 amd64 2.5-2 [25.2 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu/ trusty/main handbrake-cli amd64 7352svnppa1~trusty1 [5,705 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu/ trusty/main handbrake-gtk amd64 7352svnppa1~trusty1 [10.8 MB]
Fetched 16.6 MB in 5s (2,930 kB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package libjansson4:amd64.
(Reading database ... 247827 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjansson4_2.5-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjansson4:amd64 (2.5-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package handbrake-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../handbrake-cli_7352svnppa1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking handbrake-cli (7352svnppa1~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package handbrake-gtk.
Preparing to unpack .../handbrake-gtk_7352svnppa1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking handbrake-gtk (7352svnppa1~trusty1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Setting up libjansson4:amd64 (2.5-2) ...
Setting up handbrake-cli (7352svnppa1~trusty1) ...
Setting up handbrake-gtk (7352svnppa1~trusty1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

### But afterwards only some documentation is installed

```
jdoe@jdoe:~$ handbrake
The program 'handbrake' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install handbrake
jdoe@jdoe:~$ handbrake-gtk
The program 'handbrake-gtk' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install handbrake
jdoe@jdoe:~$ handbrake-cli
handbrake-cli: command not found

jdoe@jdoe:~$ locate handbrake
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stebbins-handbrake-snapshots-trusty.list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/stebbins-handbrake-snapshots.gpg
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/stebbins-handbrake-snapshots.gpg~
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/handbrake:ghb.desktop
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-cli
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-gtk
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-cli/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-cli/CREDITS
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-cli/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-cli/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-cli/THANKS
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-cli/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-cli/copyright
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-gtk/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/handbrake-gtk/copyright
/var/cache/apt/archives/handbrake-cli_7352svnppa1~trusty1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/handbrake-gtk_7352svnppa1~trusty1_amd64.deb
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_stebbins_handbrake-snapshots_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_stebbins_handbrake-snapshots_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release.gpg
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_stebbins_handbrake-snapshots_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_stebbins_handbrake-snapshots_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_stebbins_handbrake-snapshots_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
/var/lib/dpkg/info/handbrake-cli.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/handbrake-cli.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/handbrake-gtk.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/handbrake-gtk.md5sums
```

### And another question

Why is handbrake-cli not included in the handbrake package from the default Ubuntu repository?
Perhaps, there is a really good reason for that, that I should know :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are trying to install handbrake using [a method for Ubuntu 12.04](http://stormsail.com/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_HandBrakeCLI_on_ubuntu_12.04) while you are using Ubuntu 14.04, and this will not work in general.

Second note that in Ubuntu 12.04 the command was named `ghb` and not `handbrake`.

Third `handrake-cli` is already founded in the default PPA from universe.

Now to install handbrake in Ubuntu 14.04 properly just run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake handbrake-cli
```

But before remove the `ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots` reposioty.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots
```

---

UPDATE:

If you want to use the stebbins repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake handbrake-cli
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I must have gotten lost in all the different trial and error I was doing. Btw the executable is HandBrakeCLI

Comment: @MadsSkjern you are welcome.  If you like my answer, just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it into  green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you really like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark and the little up-arrow. Take a look on: http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Apparently the version in the repo is broken. I kept getting "MP4 muxer disabled, exiting". They recommend using the stebbins repo. http://askubuntu.com/questions/464865/handbrake-cli-updated-and-now-does-not-work. Could you add this to your answer?

Comment: @MadsSkjern check edit

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't you add that it is broken. I understand that people can read it in my comments, but I think it's better to put it in the answer?